# How to efficiently return all the column names across 1m records when certain conditions met

Tags: r, loops

Updated with dummy data and dummycode - apologies, I assumed my question was simple and you could advice the best way without a reproducible example.

```
dummy<-data.frame(prodA=c(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1),
              prodB=c(0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0),
              prodC=c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1))

dummy[,4:6]<-dummy[,1:3]

for (j in (1:nrow(dummy))){
    for (i in 4:6){
            dummy[j,i]<-ifelse(dummy[j,i]==1,colnames(dummy[i]),"")}
}
dummy2<-dummy[,4:6]
dummy$NewProds<-apply(dummy2,1,paste,collapse="") 
dummy$NewProds<-gsub(".1","//",dummy$NewProds)
```

My second attempt is as:

```
prods<-dummy[,1:3]
prods[,4:6]<-dummy[,1:3]
for (i in 4:6){
    prods[,i]<-colnames(prods[i-3])
}

prods[,7:9]<-prods[,4:6]
#works, but I will need multiple ifs for this to work, suggesting this
#won't be very efficient
prods[,10]<-ifelse(prods[,1]==1,prods[,4],"")
```

**Original Post Follows:**
I am playing with the Santander Product recommendation dataset from Kaggle.  I have identified which products have been purchased from one month to another.  This means I have 23 columns of 1's ( when a new product is added) and 0's (when not).
I created the following code to return the column name when a product has been purchased.  It works great on a sample of 6 lines, but it runs forever when I try this on the 48k customers who changed, let alone the million in the dataset.

Is there another way to do this?

```
df2[,99:122]<-df2[,72:95]

for (j in (1:nrow(df2))){
    for (i in 99:122){
            df2[j,i]<-ifelse(df2[j,i]==1,colnames(df2[i]),"")}
}
df22<-df2[,99:122]
df2$NewProds<-apply(df22,1,paste,collapse="") 
df2$NewProds<-gsub("change.1","//",df2$NewProds)
```

I figured the challenge was that I am looking at every variable and so started with another approach whereby I would take a couple of versions of the data, and then do an if variable is 1 then take the name.  However I couldn't get this to work, and I think I come to the same issue.

```
#copy a bunch of 1's and 0's
prods<-df2[,72:95]
#repeat and overwrite with colnames
prods[,25:48]<-df2[,72:95]
for (i in 25:48){
    prods[,i]<-colnames(prods[i-24])
}
prods[,49:72]<-prods[,25:48]
#attempt to only populate colnames if it was originally a 1 - doesn't work
prod[,49]<-ifelse(prod[,1]==1,prod[,25],"")
```

I haven't provided any data but I hope you can see what I am tring to do and can advise on efficient ways of doing this.
Thanks in advance, 
J

Comment: So you actually note that you haven't provided any data, but why would you not just include some and make it a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) example. If you're not going to take the time to write a good question, why would we take the time to write a good answer

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df2)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(df2[1:20, 72:95]))`.

Comment: I don't understand the output you want. The column names of the columns with at least one `1`?

Comment: I apologise.  I thought my question was simple and that this would not need dummy data.  I have provided it now and the working example.  The point here is that this works, but for the mass of data it takes far too long.  I am looking for someone who can give me a more effective way of doing this.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `apply` as @AndersEllernBilgrau illustrated is one obvious way to do it, but it will be slow for data sets with many rows.

```
dummy[["NewProds"]] <- do.call(
    paste,
    c(mapply(ifelse,
             dummy,
             names(dummy),
             MoreArgs = list(no = ""),
             SIMPLIFY = FALSE),
      sep = "//"))
```

is a bit harder to follow, but it will be much faster:

```
library(microbenchmark)

n <- 10000
dummy <- data.frame(prodA = rep(c(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1), n),
                    prodB = rep(c(0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0), n),
                    prodC = rep(c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1), n))

microbenchmark(
    do.call = do.call(
        paste,
        c(mapply(ifelse,
                 dummy,
                 names(dummy),
                 MoreArgs = list(no = ""),
                 SIMPLIFY = FALSE),
          sep = "//")),
    apply = apply(
        dummy == 1,
        1,
        function(x) paste0(names(which(x)), collapse = "//")
    ))
## Unit: milliseconds
##     expr       min        lq      mean   median       uq      max neval cld
##  do.call  63.92695  65.44777  72.07261  67.8667  73.3850 184.5151   100  a 
##    apply 296.81323 364.31947 404.71894 397.0927 443.7223 683.3892   100   b
```

Comment: Wow! I cannot believe how quick that was.  Thank you.  I need to get closer to these functions.

Answer (score 1):

Without data, I have a hard time understanding precisely what you want to do.
A couple of things are (almost) certain however:

- You probably do not need `for` loops.
- You should used R's vectorized functions, the dataset is not *that* big

Using some toy data, does the following do what you want?

```
d <- 23
n <- 46e3

# Simulate some toy data
df <- data.frame(matrix(rbinom(d*n, 1, 0.1), n, d),
                 row.names = paste0("row", 1:n))
head(df)
      X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20 X21 X22 X23
row1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
row2  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
row3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
row4  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
row5  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
row6  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0



# Paste together the colnames of all non-zero rows
res <- apply(df == 1, 1, function(x) paste0(names(which(x)), collapse = "-"))
head(res)
#    row1         row2         row3         row4         row5         row6 
#"X8-X16"         "X1"     "X8-X20" "X4-X11-X20"     "X7-X15" "X4-X18-X21"
```

I.e. `res` is here a character vector of length `n` with the colnames of each row the corresponding to 1 entries pasted together (with separator `-`). This it at least what it appears to me what your code is doing conceptually.

Comment: The OP wants `colnames`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Arh, doh

Comment: Thank you for trying.  I have updated the question with dummy data and my amended code so that it works with the dummy code.